# MCU floating pins

Tags: microcontroller, pins, floating

You'll have to excuse my ignorance I'm learning as I go along.

I would like to use a switch to toggle the state of the ESP32_EN pin in the schematic from high to low, however the pin can not be left "floating" as per the datasheet.

The datasheet also recommends using a RC delay circuit.

This is what I've come up with:

[image]

From what I understand once C7 is charged it will be open? so I guess my question is if SW1-3 is also toggled open.. I'm assuming C7 will discharge? Is the ESP32_EN pin now considered "floating" or is it being pulled to GND?

Edit: To clarify I only want EN to be high when SW1-3 is high. I also want a reset button to override this.. without it ever floating.. with of-coarse the RC delay.

When S1-3 is closed & C7 is discharged is ESP32_EN pin being pulled to GND? While in this state is the pin considered "floating"?

The schematic posted in the answer below is what I originally started with.

Edit 2: Perhaps something like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SW1-3 is some positive voltage source (it's not indicated)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLCSp2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assume that the ESP32 is an input where zero current flow into it (high impedance input). When the SW1 in my schematic is not conducting, zero current flows through R1. V=IR so zero current means zero voltage drop across R1 which means the voltage on both sides of R1 is the same which means that the pin voltage is the same as Vdd.

Then if you press SW1, current flows from Vdd to ground through R1 and SW1. The current through R1 causes a voltage drop across R1 equal to Vdd and Vdd-Vdd = 0V which ends up being the voltage on the pin. –

Of course you can also just think of it as SW1 connects the pin directly to GND (0V).

> so I guess my question is if SW1 is also toggled open.. I'm assuming C7 will discharge?

I think you mean "toggled closed" (i.e. toggled to be conducting). Yes, it will discharge C7.

> Is the ESP32_EN pin now considered "floating" or is it being pulled to GND?

After C7 discharges, the voltage drop across C7 is 0V which means it is shorting the pin to ground (remember a piece of wire ideally has 0V drop across it. Of course, the conducting switch is also shorting the pin to ground. Either perspective works.

But the pin is never floating here, even if you completely remove the switch and capacitor because the pull-up resistor is there.

> The datasheet also recommends using a RC delay circuit.

The capacitor isn't really needed. It does help to stabilize the voltage on the reset pin from fluctuating noise that may overpower the pull-up resistor to cause spurious resets, but you need a serious amount of EMI for that to happen.

> I would like to use a switch to toggle the state of the ESP32_EN

If you actually want a toggle switch instead of a button for some mysterious reason (it doesn't make sense if this is a reset pin). Then you would simply replace the SW1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsn1nZ.png)</sup>

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143039/discussion-on-answer-by-dknguyen-mcu-floating-pins); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.